# Does SELECT start transaction in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, transactions

I was told that following code won't help me to check duplicity, because result might be different before SELECT and UPDATE statement.

```
PROCEDURE AddNew(Pname VARCHAR2, Pcountry VARCHAR2)
AS
    already_exists BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)>0 INTO already_exists FROM Publishers WHERE name=Pname;
    IF already_exists THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20014,'Publisher already exists!');
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO Publishers(id,name,country)
        VALUES (NewPublisherId(),Pname,Pcountry);
END;
```

This post claims that SELECT starts a transaction:
[Why do I get an open transaction when just selecting from a database View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488853/why-do-i-get-an-open-transaction-when-just-selecting-from-a-database-view/4488944#4488944)

This part of [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10005.htm#SQLRF01705) suggests otherwise:

> A transaction implicitly begins with any operation that obtains a TX
>   lock:
>
> - When a statement that modifies data is issued
> - When a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement is issued
> - When a transaction is explicitly started with a SET TRANSACTION statement or the DBMS_TRANSACTION package

So? Does SELECT start a transaction or not?

Comment: The parameters for a procedure cannot be defined by VARCHAR2 with lengths like in your statement with VARCHAR2(40) or (30). `SELECT COUNT(*)>0 INTO` not allowed...

Comment: If you read the full post to which you linked, instead of just the accepted answer, you will see that a `SELECT` statement does not start a transaction.

Comment: By the way, are you asking whether a `SELECT` starts a transaction or are you asking for help with your stored proc? It's not clear to me.

Comment: I would suggest using  explicit transaction begin transaction  and commit transaction https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT117

Comment: @DavidFaber I've read the full post, but it's not clear to me that SELECT does not start a transaction. Can you please show me where does the documentation say that? And, what am I missing when I read the quotes in the other answer.

Comment: @srp - that won't stop the table being updated by someone else between the select and insert?

Comment: @Evka'S - there is some debate in that post, but much is about the docs not being clear. A select only seems to start a transaction if a DB link is involved, which doesn't seem to be the case for you. But you having a transaction open before the select wouldn't stop someone else modifying the table anyway. Why aren't you just using a unique constraint?

Comment: @alex i am not sure in oracle but in sqlserver there is a provision to have isolation level serializable in transaction statement. which will lock for insertion and updation and select, Have a look at this article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o65asktom-082389.html

Comment: A similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203189/why-does-not-select-query-start-the-transaction-oracle?rq=1

Comment: In any case I've definitely seen tables get updated in between `SELECT` and `INSERT` regardless of what the documentation may or may not say. Writing a stored proc this way definitely is not good practice.

Comment: This is why Nature gave us UNIQUE constraints, so that we could enforce non-duplication of values in multi-user environments.

Answer (score 4):

The latter is true: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10005.htm#SQLRF01705

> A transaction implicitly begins with any operation that obtains a TX
>   lock:
>
> - When a statement that modifies data is issued
> - When a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement is issued
> - When a transaction is explicitly started with a SET TRANSACTION statement or the DBMS_TRANSACTION package

**But it really does not matter**, from the point of view of the main problem - to see if the record already exists in the database. Even if the transaction is explicitely startet using `SET TRANSACTION ...`, your code simply does not detect duplicate transactions !
Just do a simple test manually simulating the procedure in two simultaneous sessions and you will see:

```
CREATE TABLE Publishers(
    id int,
    name varchar2(100)
);
```

Let say that in session #1 the procedure begins at 8:00:00.0000:

```
SQL> Set transaction name 'session 1';

Transaction set.

SQL> select count(*) FROM Publishers where name = 'John';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> INSERT INTO Publishers(id,name) VALUES(1,'John');

1 row created.
```

Let say that in session #2 the same procedure begins at 8:00:00.0020, just after the insert was made in session 1, but still before the session#1 commits:

```
SQL> Set transaction name 'session 2';

Transaction set.

SQL> select count(*) FROM Publishers where name = 'John';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

The transaction #2 does not see uncommited changes done by the session 1, so the session 2 assumess that there is no record `John`, so it also inserts it to the table:

```
SQL>  INSERT INTO Publishers(id,name) VALUES(1,'John');

1 row created.
```

---

Now the session 1 commits:

```
SQL> Commit;

Commit complete.
```

and a few milliseconds later the session2 commits too:

```
SQL> Commit;

Commit complete.
```

---

**And the final result is - a duplicated record even though the transaction has been explicitelly started:**

```
select * from publishers;
        ID NAME                                                                                                
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 John                                                                                                
         1 John
```

**========== EDIT =================**

> You can avoid the duplicity by executing statement SET TRANSACTION
>   ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE in the beginning. – @Draex_

Many think that `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` will solve the problem magically. **Unfortunately, it will not help**.
Let's see how it works on a simple example:
**Session #1**

```
SQL>  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

Transaction set.

SQL> select count(*) FROM Publishers where name = 'John';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> INSERT INTO Publishers(id,name) VALUES(1,'John');

1 row created.
```

**Session #2**

```
SQL> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

Transaction set.

SQL>  select count(*) FROM Publishers where name = 'John';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> INSERT INTO Publishers(id,name) VALUES(1,'John');

1 row created.
```

**Session #1 again:**

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from publishers;

        ID  NAME
----------  --------
         1  John
```

**and back to session #2**

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from publishers;
            ID  NAME
    ----------  --------
             1  John
             1  John
```

---

As you can see, the magic of `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` did not work.

Comment: You can avoid the duplicity by executing statement `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` in the beginning.

Comment: @Draex_ I've updated my question with an example how this works with `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, please take a look at it.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Do you know why is that so? I thought this was the issue of _Phantom read_, as in [On Transaction Isolation Levels](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html) which is not supposed to happen in SERIALIZABLE mode.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I could achieve what I was trying to do?

Comment: @Draex_ `Do you know why is that so?` - because the session doesn't see uncommited changes from other sessions. Isolation level Serializable does not magically change this behaviour in any way. it only **serializes locks**.